# Draw line on canvas, but under text in an UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

How can i draw this line on my canvas and image, BUT under text?

so basically the render order should be this:

1. canvas
2. image
3. line
4. text

so text would be on top of every one of them.

right now i am almost there, but the line is over the text.

i am using world space on my canvas, and the event camera is set to Main Camera.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVtfI.png)

Comment: You will need two canvases, where the second one is before the line and contains the text. Other option is to use a sprite as line and integrate it into the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a "canvas" in the Hierarchy.
2. Add a "Image" under the "canvas" in the Hierarchy.
3. Add a "GameObject" under the "Image" in the Hierarchy.
4. Add a C# script in the Assets. The C# script named as "NewBehaviourScript".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MaskableGraphic
{
    Static NewBehaviourScript self;

    NewBehaviourScript()
    {
        self = this;
    }

    // To redraw from outside this class, call NewBehaviourScript.redraw()
    static public void redraw()
    {
        print("redraw");
        self.SetAllDirty(); 
    }

    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        vh.Clear();
        UIVertex vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vertex.color = Color.red;

        // draw a diagonal red line from bottom left to top right

        // first triangle
        vertex.position = new Vector2(0, 0); // lower left position 
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        vertex.position = new Vector2(canvas.pixelRect.width+2, canvas.pixelRect.height);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        vertex.position = new Vector2(canvas.pixelRect.width-2, canvas.pixelRect.height); 
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        // second triangle
        vertex.position = new Vector2(2, 0);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        vertex.position = new Vector2(-2, 0);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        vertex.position = new Vector2(canvas.pixelRect.width, canvas.pixelRect.height); 
        // position it on the upper right.
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        // draw two elongated triangles to form a straight line
        vh.AddTriangle(0, 1, 2); // only triangles can be drawn
        vh.AddTriangle(3, 4, 5); // only triangles can be drawn
    }
}
```

4. Click the "GameObject" to show Inspector view, and click "Add component" button.
5. Add ""Canvas Renderer" into the "GameObject".
6. Drag "NewBehaviourScript" (in the assets) and drop it on the GameObject (in Hierarchy).
7. Add a "Text (Legacy)" under the "GameObject" in the hierarchy

With screen captured guide is here. This is an article I wrote.
https://kuukaix.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/10/02/181043

Comment: While this is a much better answer than your previous attempts, as you've added additional details, this version now lacks disclosure to the linked article. Please include the disclosure (i.e. make it clear that you're the author of the linked article), or remove the link entirely if the answer is sufficient on its own.

Comment: I delete the links, by the way, how to certify the linked page is mine? You know the linked page was edited at the same time as this post. Is it the certify?

Comment: You can say something like "This is an article I wrote". That is sufficient to disclose ("certify") that you are the creator of the linked content.